# What does the derivative do to an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

for the code below, I was asked a question why did I took derivative in laplacian filter. and what the **derivative actually do** to an image.  also can u tell me what the line **18** means i.e.  **original_image - filtered_image**

```
close all
clear all
j=imread('blur.png');
A = j(:,:,1);
figure,imshow(A); title('Original Image')
Original_image=A;
Filtered_Image=zeros(size(A));
F=[1 1 1;1 -8 1; 1 1 1];
A=double(A);
for k=1:size(A,1)-2
for j=1:size(A,2)-2
Filtered_Image(k,j)=sum(sum(F.*A(k:k+2,j:j+2)));

end
end
Filtered_Image= uint8(Filtered_Image);
figure,imshow(Filtered_Image);title('Filtered Image');
Deblurred_image=Original_image-5*Filtered_Image;
figure,imshow(Deblurred_image);title('Deblurred Image');
```

Comment: The Laplacian approximates the [sum of _second_ derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator#Image_Processing). As usual with derivatives, this filter enhances _edges_ . Think about it this way: if a function varies fast, its derivatives (or second derivatives) will be large. You could also see it in the (spatial) frequency domain: the Laplacian is a _high-pass filter_, which enhances rapid spatial changes

Comment: Think of the derivative of a 1-D graph. If the values are unchanging, the derivative is zero. If the values are changing greatly, the slope of the line is high and the derivative is maximized. It's roughly the same in 2-D.

Comment: both comments are good, but it is always nice to see what the derivative of an image looks like. This gives you a more intuitive understanding of how edge detectors work http://mcs.szu.edu.cn/Attach/C47C071C-1422-4773-AE3F-3F929818DCF2

Comment: thanks @Andrew can u explain me line 18 of the code please... original_image - filtered_image. why we do this?

Answer (score 3):

`F` is a Laplacian of Gaussian (LoG) kernel (2nd derivative), it is used to find edges inside of an image.

We usually use derivatives to find edges in an image because the derivative tells the rate of change. In an image an edge is usually marked by sharp changes in intensity which means they also have a large derivative. The first derivative usually shows a max or min at an edge.  We usually threshold the first derivative to find an edge. Second derivative detectors, like the LoG are actually mark edges by a zero crossing. Look at the 2nd derivative kernal, it increases the contrast of the pixels arund an edge, the edge itself is 0. Both methods are meant to exaggerate edges
[image]

back to your question. If our filtered image is the result of our LoG operation that means `Filtered_Image` contains the edges of our image. So if we subtract the edges from the image `original - filtered` we are actually emphasizing the edges.